# Duvida com o comando Sender dos objetos de Outlook do VBA excel

Tags: excel-vba

tenho um código em VBA do excel, que envia para alguns destinatários específicos alguns e-mail's, mas a principio esses e-mail como estão sendo enviado pelo meu outlook estão saindo com meu nome, mas no Outlook temos a opção de digitar a partir de qual nome você deseja enviar esse e-mail que e o campo "DE". A minha duvida e, como coloco no código para ele enviar a partir de outro nome, através desse campo "DE", sem ser pelo meu nome? Pesquisando eu encontrei o comando Sender, mas quando utilizo ele esta dando a mensagem "Erro de compilação - Tipos Incompatíveis". Abaixo sege a linha de código para envio de e-mail, conseguem me ajudar por favor.

```
Sub Enviar_e_mail()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
'Criação e chamada do Objeto Outlook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With OutMail
.Sender = "AeC-RH-DiagnosticoPontoMatriz@aec.com.br"
.To = "rogerio.junior@aec.com.br"
'.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Titulo do e-mail"
.Body = "Texto do E-mail"
'O trecho abaixo anexa a planilha ao e-mail
.Attachments.Add "Arquivo a ser anexado"
.Send
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso um código como a seguir para enviar emails aqui no trabalho:

```
Set oMensagem = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set oConfiguração = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

oConfiguração.Load -1 'Padrões CDO
Set vFields = oConfiguração.Fields

With vFields
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.***.com.br"

  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "***@***.com.br"
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "SENHA"
  .Update
End With

With oMensagem

  Set .Configuration = oConfiguração
  .to = PARA
  .CC = COM_COPIA
  .BCC = COM_COPIA_OCULTA
  .From = "***@***.com.br"
  .ReplyTo = "suporte@***.com.br"
  .Subject = ASSUNTO
  .AddAttachment (MyFile)
  .HTMLBody = TEXTO & ASSINATURA
  .Send

End With
```

Só cortei os trechos que definem as variáveis utilizadas...